# Laravel Livewire errors are not cleared

Tags: laravel-validation, laravel-livewire

I am experimenting with Laravel Livewire and I came across a situation where the previous errors are displayed even though the form is successfully submitted.

*Before hit Save*

[image: beforeSend]

*After hitting Save*

[image: afterSend]

Html segment of `name` in blade file `customer-new.blade.php`.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="border rounded-0 px-1">
        <label class="mb-0" for="name">Name</label>
        <input wire:model="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="customer-name" aria-describedby="customer-nameHelp">
    </div>
    @error('name') <span class="err-message">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

and the *Save* button code:

```html
<button 
  wire:click="store" 
  wire:loading.attr="disabled" 
  wire:target="store" 
  type="submit" 
  class="btn btn-sm btn-light">Save
</button>
```

`store` method of CustomerNew.php:

```php
public function store()
{
    $this->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:80',
        'street' => 'required|max:100',
        'city' => 'required|max:40',
        'dueAmount' => 'numeric|min:0'
    ]);

    Customer::create([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'street' => $this->street,
        'city' => $this->city,
        'due_amount' => $this->dueAmount,
    ]);

    session()->flash('message', 'Customer was saved');

    $this->clear();
}
```

and the `clear()` method is like:

```php
public function clear() {
  $this - > name = '';
  $this - > street = '';
  $this - > city = '';
  $this - > dueAmount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've not sending the form twice? Be sure to not use a submit button when using `<form wire:submit.prevent="store">` when already submiting the form via the button.

Answer (score 29):

According to docs https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/input-validation,

You need to reset the validations whenever you want

> Direct Error Message Manipulation The validate() and validateOnly()
> method should handle most cases, but sometimes you may want direct
> control over Livewire's internal ErrorBag.
>
> Livewire provides a handful of methods for you to directly manipulate
> the ErrorBag.
>
> From anywhere inside a Livewire component class, you can call the
> following methods:
>
> ```php
>     $this->addError('email', 'The email field is invalid.');
>     // Quickly add a validation message to the error bag.
>     
>     $this->resetErrorBag();
>     $this->resetValidation();
>     // These two methods do the same thing. The clear the error bag.
>     // If you only want to clear errors for one key, you can use:
>     $this->resetValidation('email');
>     $this->resetErrorBag('email');
>     
>     $errors = $this->getErrorBag();
>     // This will give you full access to the error bag,
>     // allowing you to do things like this:
>     $errors->add('some-key', 'Some message');
> ```

**HINT**

I am using the reset methods on hydrate function like following

```php
...
    public function hydrate()
    {
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->resetValidation();
    }
...
```

Comment: I guess calling `$this->resetValidation()` is enough, since it called `resetErrorBag()` method internally

Answer (score 1):

It is better to send `$name` to the `resetValidation` and `resetErrorBug`. In this way you reset validation for the updating fields only. Here is my example:

```
    public function updated($name, $value)
    {
        $this->resetValidation($name);
        $this->resetErrorBag($name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, using the methods mentioned above is more than enough, and they should solve all your issues:

```
$this->resetErrorBag();
$this->resetValidation();
```

However, in practice, these errors may not disappear. As an alternative solution, you can apply the following approach:

1. Add event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('reset-error', event => {
    const paragraph = document.getElementById(event.detail.id += '-error');
    if (paragraph) {
        paragraph.textContent = '';
    }
});
```

2. Dispatch browser event:

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('reset-error', ['id' => "sandbox"]);
```

This should be enough for now, but if you encounter any issues or have further questions, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the public properties by using the livewire's `reset` method. Delete your `$this->clear()` method definition and replace it with the following:

```php
$this->reset('name', 'street', 'city', 'dueAmount');
```

Comment: Won't these clear the input instead of clearing the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

add id's to the error message div

```
@error('name') <span class="err-message" id="name-error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

@error('street') <span class="err-message" id="street-error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

@error('city') <span class="err-message" id="city-error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

@error('due_amount') <span class="err-message" id="due_amount-error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $this->resetErrorBag();
```

Just add this in your `clear()` method. This will reset the error bag after each save.